# Understanding behavior of regex when using consecutive \d and \w

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `regex` when using `\d` and `\w` consecutively to match words and numbers in a sentence. I searched for similar questions but I couldn't find a good match (please let me know if this is somehow duplicate).

```
# Example sentence
"Adam has 100 friends. Bill has 23 friends. Cindy has 5 friends."
```

When I use regex `[A-Za-z]+\s\w+\s\d+\w`, it returns matches for:

- `Adam has 100`
- `Bill has 23`

**BUT NOT FOR**

- `Cindy has 5`

I would have expected no matches at all since the greedily searched digits (`\d+`) are not followed by any word character (`\w`); they are followed by a white space instead. I think, somehow `\w` is matching digits following the first occurrence of any digit. I thought `\d+` would have exhausted the stretch of digits in the search. Can you help me understand what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of answer you expect? Explanation of how the pattern works? Then see https://regex101.com/r/LWD5hM/1/debugger

Comment: Hi Wiktor. I didn't understand the behavior initially, because I didn't know about backtracking to accommodate more of the query pattern by greedy matching. The answer below clarifies it. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought \d+ would have exhausted the stretch of digits in the search

No that is not the case. `\d+` matches as many digits as it can before next `\w` (that also matches digit i.e. `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`) forces regex engine to backtrack one position so that `\w` can match one word character.

If you don't want this backtracking to happen then use [**possessive quantifier `++`**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
[A-Za-z]+\s\w+\s\d++\w
```

However note that `\d++w` pattern will always fail for all 3 cases because `\d++` won't backtrack and `\w` will never be able to match a digit.

This pattern will succeed only if there is non-digit word character in the end like `Chapter is 23A`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sualem/1)

Comment: Because not all regex flavours support possessive quantifiers, an atomic group may be a more general solution.

Comment: Yes agreed but even atomic groups are not supported on all regex flavours

Comment: @Atakan: Just for reference `[A-Za-z]+\s\w+\s(?>\d+)\w` is regex using an atomic group